# <p:commandButton> image shows ui-button over the button image

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to show a button as an image.So I have written it like:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="edit_button_image" actionListener="#{userLeaveBean.editAppliedLeave}" title="Edit" process="@this"/>
```

and the CSS for getting the button image:

```
.edit_button_image{
background: url(edit.JPG) no-repeat !important;
```

}

it shows the image well, but also shows a text "ui-button" over the image.
How can I get the image only?
Using  it shows fine, since I want to execute some action on a part of the entire for I chose  and added process="@this".any Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this be way easier? A `p:commandLink` submits a POST just like a `p:commandButton`.

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandLink ...>
        <h:graphicImage ... />
    </p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Comment: @NGH You're welcome. Since you haven't discovered on how to accept answer according to your history: You should 'accept' answers by clicking the mark on the left of the answer in case you feel it solves your question. This helps future readers to identify the right solution to the question (this also applies for your previous questions).

Comment: I tried buddy..But said I have to wait till 2mins,so was taking that Time..:)